# ORMLite mixing orderBy() and orderByRaw()

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I want to query a list of items from my database using ORMLite. The ordering must be a bit field, then the nullability of a field, then a date field.  Here is what I have at the moment:

```
 QueryBuilder<Task, Integer> queryBuilder = mTaskDao.queryBuilder();
        queryBuilder
        .orderBy("done", true)
        .orderByRaw("visit_id is null desc")
        .orderBy("duedate", true);
```

When I call `getStatement()` on the above query however, it returns the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `task` ORDER BY visit_id is null
```

Notice only orderByRaw had an effect on the QueryBuilder. Reading the [QueryBuilder code](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.java) I see method `appendOrderBys` ignores non RawOrderBy statements, if orderByRaw is non null.

Ideally it should have generated the orderBy and orderByRaw in correct order.

Only workaround I can think of for now is to set all my order by clauses in the `orderByRaw()` method.

Comment: This was fixed in 4.48.  Let me know if it now works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comeback @Gray.  The order of the orderBy clauses is incorrect unfortunately when mixing normal and raw.  The query in version 4.48 for my original query looks like this `SELECT * FROM `task` ORDER BY visit_id is null desc,done,dueDate` notice the orderByRaw is first, but my intention is to set it as second clause.

Comment: Sigh.  Yeah, I figured this out late yesterday unfortunately.  Stupid.  I've fixed this in trunk.  Can you work from the code or should I put out another version?

Comment: My workaround is to call all the orderbys as one orderbyraw. Quick fix is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice only orderByRaw had an effect on the QueryBuilder. Reading the QueryBuilder code I see method appendOrderBys ignores non RawOrderBy statements, if orderByRaw is non null.

Yeah.  This looks to be a limitation of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) right now.  It seems like it either handles the raw or the non.  See this code here around like 757.

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/e11db21da474e9e0d4004cd83fa9f71c3d4e66e3/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.java#L757

This is not documented at all that they are mutually exclusive and I can see no reason why they should be.  I've added this bug:

> https://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/161/

A fix for it has been checked into trunk and was released on 12/16/2013 in version 4.48.

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/36492cebc1506b0b75f3a6f72569ec25de776aec